# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at / CustomUser has no customer

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-allauth

Hlw,I am working on a Djang0 2.2.15 project,I used allauth to set up my user account,I used a function called def cartData(request):   in utils.py that I called in views.py function,

```
    def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         customer = request.user.customer
         order, created = 
         Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, 
         complete=False)
         items = order.orderitem_set.all()
         cartItems = order.get_cart_items
     else:
          cookieData = cookieCart(request)
          cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
          order = cookieData['order']
          items = cookieData['items']

      return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items}
```

In models.py the class which I used  onetoone relationship with user is,

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Customer(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, 
     blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

But i whenever I run my project I found this error on console,

```
users.models.CustomUser.customer.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: CustomUser 
has no customer.
```

the screenshot for error message in the browser is given below,

[Browser error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StIhi.png)
[Browser error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKGio.png)

forms.py from which I created a user ,the code for this is given below

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)
```

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)
```

The code of users/views.py is given below,

```
from django.views import generic

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignupPageView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Comment: obviously the Customer instance was not created when you have created an User object. Better check your signal/form(by which you have created Customer instance)

Comment: I upadated my question and added a forms,py code,from which I created a user,can you please suggest me to creating a Customer instance

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code for `CustomUserCreationForm` should only create `User` instance, it does not create any `Customer` instnace. So you can change the form code to create the Customer object. Like this:

```
#create_form
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)

    def save(self, commit=False):
        user = super().save(commit=True)
        # Creating the customer object
        Customer.objects.create(user=user, name=self.cleaned_data['name'], email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        return user

# update form
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'username',)

    def save(self, commit=False):
          user = super().save(commit=True)
          Customer.objects.update_or_create(user=user, name=self.cleaned_data['name'], email=self.cleaned_data['email'], defaults={'user':user})
          return user
```

FYI, you do not need to store `email` and `name` information as it already being stored in `User` model. If you need to access them, then user `user.customer.name` or `user.customer.email`.

Comment: If I use user.customer.name  or user.customer.email then it shows user is not defined

Comment: Please see the updated answer. But for the old users, you need to update those users using CustomUpdateUser form

Comment: Again I am recieving same error,should I delete all user and then add,Actually I am quite beginner so how to update using CustomUpdateUser

Comment: if you can delete users then sure. But if you have issues with newly created User then its better to share your code with view

Comment: I tried all the way you mentioned,but same error happend,can you please tell me which codes do you want,my views.py code is given below the questions

Comment: Sry,ok I will share it,but as I use Django allauth account,does views.py could anything?

Comment: hello are you here,Now I am finding error  
  Customer.objects.create(user=user, email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
NameError: name 'Customer' is not defined
  You helped me a lot,please help me in this time.May be you can solve the problem

Comment: You need to import that class from your models. 'from . models import Customer'

Comment: I imported that,will you please tell me the instances created in the forms.py how can I save save it in users/views.py ,this time I am getting this error
   Cannot query "muntasir": Must be "Customer" instance.